# CMake OpenCV 3.0.0 and building executables and libraries in Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have OpenCV 3.0.0 installed in /usr/local/opencv-3.0.0

I am trying to construct a CMakeLists file to build a library against this OpenCV 3.0.0. The CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(STT_People_Tracker)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0016 NEW)

# compilation mode setup
#set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

# set OpenCV directories - CHANGE DEPENDING ON SYSTEM
set(OpenCV_PATH "/usr/local/opencv-3.0.0")
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OpenCV_PATH}/include")
set(OpenCV_LIBS "${OpenCV_PATH}/lib/")

# set environment variables
set(SOURCES_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources")
set(INCLUDES_PATH "${SOURCES_PATH}/include")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    set(OUTPUT_PATH "../Debug")
    message(STATUS "Compiling in DEBUG mode")
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
    set(OUTPUT_PATH "../Release")
    message(STATUS "Compiling in RELEASE mode")
endif()

include_directories(${INCLUDES_PATH})
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# compilation of executables
message(STATUS "configuring executables...")
add_executable(${OUTPUT_PATH}/mainTest ${SOURCES_PATH}/mainTest.cpp)

# compilation of libraries
message(STATUS "configuring libraries...")
add_library(${OUTPUT_PATH}/background_substractor ${SOURCES_PATH}/background_substractor.cpp)

# set linker options
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(${OUTPUT_PATH}/mainTest opencv_core opencv_highgui)
target_link_libraries(${OUTPUT_PATH}/background_substractor opencv_core opencv_highgui)

message(STATUS "cmake configuration complete")
```

It is a fairly simple Cmake file, however, I have the following problems/doubts:
1.-How can I know I am using OpenCV 3, and not other versions of OpenCV present in the system?
2.- When compiling the file background_substractor, its associated header file can not be located, although I have checked the path and it is correctly assigned in the set(INCLUDES_PATH "${SOURCES_PATH}/include"):

```
/home/alberto/STT_People_Tracking/Sources/background_substractor.cpp:3:36: fatal error: background_substractor.h: No such file or directory
 #include "background_substractor.h"
                                    ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/../Debug/background_substractor.dir/Sources/background_substractor.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/../Debug/background_substractor.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

3.- Finally, and if I comment the header file, I have problems linking:

```
Linking CXX static library lib../Debug/background_substractor.a
/usr/bin/ar: lib../Debug/background_substractor.a: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [lib../Debug/background_substractor.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/../Debug/background_substractor.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried everything: Specifying the include files in the add_executable() and add_library() commands, I have checked paths and they are ok, etc etc.

Could anyone more experienced with CMake, give me a little hand?
Thank you very much in advance,

Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I know I am using OpenCV 3, and not other versions of OpenCV present in the system?

Your project should check that.

But usually projects just use [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) command for fill variables related to 3d-party library. This command perform all needed checks. In your case it could be

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
```

call, which fills `OpenCV_LIBS` and `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` variables automatically. This command, by default, search OpenCV installation in *default paths*, but you can adjust searching algorithm by using parameters to `cmake` (so, you needn't to change `CMakeLists.txt` when you build the project on other machine). E.g., this way

```
cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/opencv-3.0.0 <source-dir>
```

you can specify precise installation path of OpenCV.

> 2. When compiling the file background_substractor, its associated header file can not be located...

Cannot suggest anything aside from checking file existence

```
/home/alberto/STT_People_Tracking/Sources/include/background_substractor.h
```

But this also can be a result of the 3d issue(see below).

> 3. Finally, and if I comment the header file, I have problems linking...

Your usage of *CMake targets* is incorrect. Unlike to *make targets*, which usually are files, **CMake targets are simple names**. By default, *name of library/executable target* determines filename of the library/executable file, produced by this target, but this can be changed. Directory, where resulted file will be located, can be adjusted using `CMAKE_<TYPE>_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variables, where `<TYPE>` can be `ARCHIVE`, `LIBRARY` or `RUNTIME` depending on target type.

Correct CMake script would be:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(STT_People_Tracker)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0016 NEW)

# compilation mode setup
#set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

# set OpenCV directories using find_package.
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)

# set environment variables
set(SOURCES_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources")
set(INCLUDES_PATH "${SOURCES_PATH}/include")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    set(OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug") # Use absolute path
    message(STATUS "Compiling in DEBUG mode")
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
    set(OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release")
    message(STATUS "Compiling in RELEASE mode")
endif()

# Set output directory for STATIC libraries and executables
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_PATH})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_PATH})

include_directories(${INCLUDES_PATH})
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# compilation of executables
message(STATUS "configuring executables...")
add_executable(mainTest ${SOURCES_PATH}/mainTest.cpp) # Use simple name as a target

# compilation of libraries
message(STATUS "configuring libraries...")
add_library(background_substractor ${SOURCES_PATH}/background_substractor.cpp)  # Use simple name as a target

# set linker options
# Command below is no-op: OpenCV libraries enumerated using absolute paths
# link_directories(${OpenCV_LINK_DIRECTORIES})
target_link_libraries(mainTest ${OpenCV_LIBS}) # Variable OpenCV_LIBS contains OpenCV libraries needed to link with
target_link_libraries(background_substractor ${OpenCV_LIBS})

message(STATUS "cmake configuration complete")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That clarifies some concepts. Anyway I wanted to avoid "find_package()" instruction, because the installation of OpenCV 3 does not provide any *.cmake file by default. How could I solve this? find_package() is locating my 2.4.8 version of OpenCV, installed with ROS

Comment: There is `findOpenCV.cmake` file, which comes with CMake installation, not with OpenCV itself. For specify path to installation, use method I have described in the post. Note, that **for change package, already located by `find_package` call, you need to clean CMake cache** (remove `CMakeCache.txt` file).

Comment: There is a OpenCVConfig.cmake in /usr/local/opencv-3.0.0/share/OpenCV. If I do cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/opencv-3.0.0 .. does not work, however, if I do cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/opencv-3.0.0/share/OpenCV .. it does. findOpenCV.cmake finds the 2.4.8 version of the library which I have installed along with ROS.....

Comment: Also, the exe goes to the correct path specified in CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, but the library is created where the Makefile is, no matter the value of CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY....

Comment: Oh, just found from your error log, that you build STATIC library. For such type of libraries output directory is controlled by `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable. As for `find_package()`, its usage is tricky very often. For toy project it is sufficient to use predefined variables. (But use `OpenCV_LINK_DIRECTORIES` instead of `OpenCV_LIBS` as directory with libraries files, it is just a naming convention).